# Does using a CSS class ".one-liner" go against the practice of semantic design?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I think it is said that CSS class names such as:

```
.top-stories
.promotions
.about-the-company
```

are good names because it has meaning, or semantics.  A class name such as `.bold-text` or `.big-font` are normally not recommended because it is a name tied too tight with presentation style.  So the idea is, we should use class name with meaning, rather than the style it should have.

So what about a class name such as `.one-liner`?  I actually thought of it as a good form, because it captures 3 meanings:

```
text-overflow: ellipses;
height: 1.2em;
width: 90%;
```

And I feel quite confident to style them as `height: 1.6em`, or `width: 83%` (of the container), vs if it is some specific names, such as `link-to-product-page`, because such styling is more "loose" rather than packed together, like data structure or objects with attributes and methods in programming.

However, if we compare `.one-liner` to `.bold-text` or `.big-font`, they actually might be similar.  So is it actually not a good practice to name it `.one-liner` but as a best practice, use `.product-title` and style it as a one liner?

But what if we use it as

```
<div class="product-title">
    <span class="one-liner">Sandisk 32GB Flash Drive</span>
</div>
```

or

```
<span class="product-title one-liner">Sandisk 32GB Flash Drive</span>
```

?  If we think about Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation, they use `.col-sm-4` which are also higher level styling names too.  Also, no matter what element it is, we could expect to add the class `.one-liner` and make it one line, so it is a good, abstracted usage, as in abstraction or black-box in programming.  So isn't `.one-liner` not necessarily a bad practice?

Comment: Depends on individual actually,but i feel keeping class name with meaning is a good semantic practice and best practice.

Comment: But in a responsive, mobile first web where you don't know the screen size of the device, how do you know that a span of .one-liner will always fit on one line?

Comment: `one-liner` *used as you described* does fall in the same category as `bold-text` because you're using it to describe the styling, not the content. A "one-liner" is also a way to describe a joke. If your class was being used to tag content that was such a joke, that would be an appropriate use. Bootstrap, and other such frameworks, are full of bad class names because they are trying to shoehorn a styling practice that CSS was never designed to work with.

Comment: yes, actually a "concise title" (like a one-liner joke) actually go with the semantic principle.  By the way, all the frameworks, using `.hide` etc, actually could be said to be against semantic markup... but they do provide a good solution... imagining if the JS frameworks add individual CSS style vs adding a class.  A class will be much cleaner and better abstracted. And millions of people and companies use Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation too...

Comment: @LDJ oops, I meant to type height but typed it as line-height at first.  
if it is width of 90%, height of 1.2em, and with text-overflow as ellipses, then isn't it guaranteed to be 1 line?